# User / Client IP restrictions in Postgres running on RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm looking to restrict connection access for specific accounts based on the client IP. All of our services are running on AWS so I want an account that has R/W permissions to only be able to connect to Postgres when coming from inside our containers.

I would be able to configure `pg_hba.conf` if this was a native version of Postgres running but that is not possible with RDS. The only access management I can see is completely blocking access by IP with no regards to the credentials being used. Credential management is for RDS access but since we are connecting directly to Postgres none of that is used.

Has anyone found a way around this issue?